# Spring Boot filter pattern matches wrong urls

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, filter, spring-boot, servlet-filters

I am working on a Spring Boot web application. It contains the following configuration class:

```java
@Configuration
public class FilterRegistration {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean provideTestFilter() {
        final FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
                throw new RuntimeException("I shouldn't be thrown!");
            }
        });
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/users/*");
        return registrationBean;
    }

}
```

I can tell that the filter was registered successfully, because, during startup, the console logs the following entry:

```
o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'oncePerRequestFilter' to urls: [/users/*]
```

When I test the endpoints, I get the following results:

`curl localhost:8080/users/bob` -> `{"status": 500, "message": "I shouldn't be thrown!"}`

`curl localhost:8080/users/` -> `{"status": 500, "message": "I shouldn't be thrown!"}`

`curl localhost:8080/users` -> `{"status": 500, "message": "I shouldn't be thrown!"}`

`curl localhost:8080/usersx` -> `{"status": 404, "error": "Not Found"}`

The first and last results are expected, but why does the url pattern `/users/*` match the urls `/users/` and `/users` as well?

Is there a different syntax for Spring url patterns to **_not_** match these two urls, and only match `/users/bob`, `/users/alice` or `/users/any_non_empty_string`?

Comment: You can add a `if (request.getRequestURI().matches("/users/.*"))` around your filter logic..

Comment: @AliDehghani
I see, but I would rather not have my filter know about the urls to which it will be applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter pattern is behaving exactly as it should according to the Servlet spec. The spec describes mappings in terms of Servlets, but the same rules apply to Filters too. It provides the following example mappings:

- `/foo/bar/*` mapped to `servlet1`
- `/baz/*` mapped to `servlet2`
- `/catalog` mapped to `servlet3`
- `*.bop` mapped to `servlet4`

Given these mappings, the following behaviour will result:

- `/foo/bar/index.html` handled by `servlet1`
- `/foo/bar/index.bop` handled by `servlet1`
- `/baz` handled by `servlet2`
- `/baz/index.html` handled by `servlet2`
- `/catalog` handled by `servlet3`
- `/catalog/index.html` handled by `default servlet`
- `/catalog/racecar.bop` handled by `servlet4`
- `/index.bop` handled by `servlet4`

The case that you have described is the same as a request for `/baz` being handled by `servlet2` which is mapped to `/baz/*`.

> Is there a different syntax for Spring url patterns to *not* match these two urls, and only match /users/bob, /users/alice or /users/any_non_empty_string?

As shown by the examples above, the Servlet spec doesn't provide support for such a mapping. You'll need to add some logic to handle that case. You could either do that directly in the filter, or in another filter that runs first and sets a request attribute telling the other filter to ignore the request.